# Convert seconds to h.m in a double

Tags: delphi

I would like to convert an integer holding seconds in to a double where the integer part is the hours and the decimal part is the minutes.

Is there a better way to do this than by doing like this? (the r value)

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SecStr : string;
  SumSeconds : integer;
  m : word;
  h : word;
  d : Word;
  r : Real;
  t : TDateTime;
  x : word;

begin
  SecStr := InputBox('Convert seconds', 'Enter seconds', '1177530');
  if TryStrToInt(SecStr, SumSeconds) then
  begin
      r := 0.0;
      x := 0;
      // SumSeconds := ASummary.Sum;

      h := SumSeconds div (MinsPerHour * SecsPerMin);
      SumSeconds := SumSeconds - (h * (MinsPerHour * SecsPerMin));

      m := SumSeconds div (SecsPerMin);

      ShowMessageFmt('%d hours and %d minutes',[h, m]);

      r := StrToFloat(format('%d%s%d',[h,formatsettings.DecimalSeparator, m]))

  end;
end;
```

Comment: `t := InitDateTime + (NumSeconds / SecsPerDay)` where `InitDateTime` is a `TDateTime` since when you want to calculate and `NumSeconds` is the number of seconds that you have.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not related to  a specific date or time, this is purely a accumulated seconds value, e.g. 11775530 seconds (not since anything) and I wan't to convert than value into a float, having the format "hours.minutes" where hours can be any integer number but minutes can be within 0..59

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a local variable

```
minutes: Integer;
```

then calculate

```
  minutes := SumSeconds div SecsPerMin;

  h := minutes div MinsPerHour;
  m := minutes mod MinsPerHour;

  r := h + m/100;
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of complete hours is given by:

```
WholeHours := TotalSeconds div SecondsPerHour;
```

The number of seconds remaining is:

```
SecondsRemaining := TotalSeconds - WholeHours * SecondsPerHour;
```

Or alternatively:

```
SecondsRemaining := TotalSeconds mod SecondsPerHour;
```

The remaining seconds in fractional form is given by:

```
FractionalHours := SecondsRemaining / SecondsPerHour;
```

So, your final answer is:

```
WholeHours + FractionalHours
```

Then again, perhaps you wish to know the number of complete minutes remaining, after the hours have been removed, as @LURD suggests. That would be:

```
WholeMinutes := SecondsRemaining div SecondsPerMinute;
```

And then the final answer would be:

```
WholeHours + WholeMinutes / MinutesPerHour
```

As yet another option, in order to calculate hours, minutes and seconds, the code runs like this:

```
SecondsRemaining := TotalSeconds;
Hours := SecondsRemaining div SecondsPerHour;
dec(SecondsRemaining, Hours * SecondsPerHour);
Minutes := SecondsRemaining div SecondsPerMinute;
dec(SecondsRemaining, Minutes * SecondsPerMinute);
Seconds := SecondsRemaining;
```

Comment: As I understood, the fractional part should only contain the minute (0..59) information.

Comment: Thanks David, the main issue was how to assign the float with hours and minutes as fraction (sorry my English lacks a bit here) - of course it's especially the fraction which was bugging me. I thought of using a shr or something to assign that but the below suggestion (r := h + m/100) appears to be working just fine and solves it.

Comment: @nedergah I for sure would not do m/100.  That's a meaningless quantity, on which you cannot perform arithmetic. It's quite clear to me that you are going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

```
r := DateUtils.HourSpan(0,(sumSeconds div SecsPerMin)/MinsPerDay);
```

or

```
var
  hours,seconds: Word;
...
Math.DivMod(sumSeconds,MinsPerHour * SecsPerMin,hours,seconds);
r := hours + (seconds div SecsPerMin)/MinsPerHour;
```